# How to stop background music with button and if/else in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my game I added a button to the GameScene and played music:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Happy Background Music", withExtension: "mp3")
let bgMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)

@IBAction func SoundOnOff(sender: UIButton) {
    bgMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
    bgMusic.play()
}
```

and the music played, but I want to add an if so when the button is pressed the music will stop. What if should I write?

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit or some other game framework to write your game?

Comment: I'm using Sprite kit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84780/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-zaid-pathan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this,

```
 let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Happy Background Music", withExtension: "mp3")

    do{
        let bgMusic = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }


@IBAction func SoundOnOff(sender: UIButton) {

if bgMusic.playing {
        bgMusic.stop()
    } else {
        self.bgMusic.play()
    }
}
```

**Edit: Description**

> [playing- Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/playing) 
>   -A Boolean value that indicates whether the audio player is playing (true) or not (false). (read-only)

Comment: the part with "let bgMusic = ..." is problem in Xcode 7.2.1

Answer (score 1):

`AVAudioPlayer` has a built-in property [`playing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/playing), which you can use to decide whether to play or pause the music:

```
@IBAction func SoundOnOff(sender: UIButton) {
    if bgMusic.playing {
        bgMusic.pause()
    } else {
        bgMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
        bgMusic.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just seen that this is only available in iOS9 and later. So if you're targeting iOS9 then this is possible.

If you're using SpriteKit to write your game I would recommend using the `SKAudioNode` class to play your BGMusic.

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Happy Background Music", withExtension: "mp3")
let audioNode = SKAudioNode(URL:url)
audioNode.positional = false
audioNode.autoplayLooped = true
self.addChild(audioNode)
```

To pause the music you create an `SKAction` ...

```
let pauseAction = SKAction.pause()
audioNode.runAction(pauseAction)
```

You can resume it also but just trying to find the code for that...

Comment: Please can you help. i put my bgMusic.mp3 to main project setup you code and nothing works im also import AVFoundation. no luck